# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ToolStripDropDownMenu'

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exception

I see a few other posts discussing the same issue, but most of the are using multithreading or timers, which is not the case here.

I'm using a simple VB.NET (.net 4.0) desktop app with a `MenuStrip` containing standard `File > Exit` item. The code for File > Exit item is simply `Me.Close()`. Clicking the item through mouse or using keyboard shortcut (`Alt + F, X`) raises the following exception:

```
{"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ToolStripDropDownMenu'."}
```

Interestingly, closing the same application through `Alt + F4` sequence or the Close button of the window works smoothly.

I checked the stack trace and it seems like it is trying to create the handle of that menu item AFTER the application has closed. Any insight would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Double check that you don't have code that does that handling close events or something like that. Look at the stack trace for user-code methods.

Comment: I checked stack trace in detail, and there's no line belonging to my code.

Comment: If File->Exit is supposed to close the app, try `Application.Exit` instead.  It sounds like the form close/destroy happens then the App Exit code tries to do it again.

Comment: Interestingly, `Application.Exit` works without a problem. Wondering... :|

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the ToolStrip after it was disposed... What's the call stack look like? It should show you what is attempting to access it. I'm guessing some sort of event. Can you prune it down to a simple example to replicate the problem and post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had something similar happen, but was not sure is you were closing a form or the app, so this started as a comment.  I think it partly depends on whether you have `Enable NET application framework` checked in the project.  IF you do, I think Me.Close will work, if not, Application.Exit needs (?) to be explicitly called.

If File->Exit is supposed to close the app, try `Application.Exit` instead. It sounds like the form close/destroy happens then the App Exit code tries to do it again.

Comment: This fixed my problem. For record, I am using application framework.